# ¿Puedo usar codigo open source de otro desarrollador para uso comercial?

Tags: android, licencias, gpl

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para fines comerciales en android y quiero saber si puedo usar una versión modificada de los ejemplos que están disponibles en developer.android.com o tengo que escribir código original
Quiero saber de estos temas legales sobre licencias de software antes de meterme en problemas

Gracias :D

EDIT1: gracias por sus comentarios, he leído los artículos y llegue a las siguientes conclusiones :
1) Puedo usar contenido de terceros en mi aplicación siempre y cuando tenga las licencias respectivas, sea cual sea su tipo. 
2) No estoy obligado a revelar ni compartir el código fuente de mi aplicación. 
3) Para comercializar mi aplicación tengo que cumplir con los requerimientos, términos y condiciones impuestos por Google en la plataforma Developers Console

Corrijanme si estoy equivocado, cualquier feedback es bienvenido.

Comment: Si son bajo GPL, MIT no hay problema, si te lees ya lo pone claro que las puedes utilizar para uso comercial.

Comment: [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/legal.html) puedes ver que los ejemplos son para usarse, modificarse y distribuirse, los tutoriales y los ejemplo de código estan *licenciados* bajo [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Comment: @Webserveis : Eso no es cierto para GPL : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47032/can-i-use-gpl-software-in-a-commercial-application

Comment: @ARAdev No me queda claro si estás hablando del caso general o del particular que consultas (ejemplos de `developer.android.com`). Contesto sobre el general: 1) aclaración, siempre que la licencia sea adecuada para el uso que le estás dando; 2) No, depende de la licencia. Ejemplo GPL es copyleft (lo que informa leonboy); 3) La plataforma de Google es de distribución, sus términos aplican sea que cobres o no por la aplicación. Por otro lado, no estás obligado a usar la plataforma para distribuir tu aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

Que un proyecto sea de código abierto no implica que sea gratis o su licencia permita su uso para fines comerciales. En cada caso, debes leer los términos de la licencia.

Como se [aquí](https://developer.android.com/legal.html) el licenciamiento del código de `developer.android.com` esta licenciado bajo [Apache License Version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). Para poder usarlo debes cumplir con los requisitos de la misma, en particular el punto 4 habla sobre la redistribución de los fuentes u objetos, sea del código en sí (el que obtuviste de la página) o trabajos derivados del mismo.