# ¿Cómo subir una aplicación al Google Play con todos los derechos de copyright?

Tags: android, google-play, licencias

He realizado una aplicación que me gustaría subir al `Google Play`. Sin embargo, no quiero hacerlo de cualquier manera y quiero proteger mi aplicación y, a la vez, no meterme en problemas legales.

Lo que quiero básicamente para mi aplicación es tener todo el derecho sobre ella, es decir, que nadie pueda modificar, distribuir, comercializar, etc. mi aplicación ni el código en ella contenido. Tampoco el logo ni que puedan copiar la aplicación (en cuanto a nombre y funcionalidad se refiere).

He visto las preguntas que hay en este sitio sobre licencias y creo que las que más se adaptan a mis necesidades son estas:

- [Licencias en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32704/licencias-en-android)
- [DMCA (Digital Millennium Copyright Act)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23550/dmca-digital-millennium-copyright-act)
- [¿Puedo usar codigo open source de otro desarrollador para uso comercial?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22101/puedo-usar-codigo-open-source-de-otro-desarrollador-para-uso-comercial)

Sin embargo, he visto que para poder utilizar el código que está en la documentación de Android (que usa una licencia Apache), tienes que publicar la licencia correspondiente junto con el código. Además, no sé como debería de agregar esta licencia a la aplicación ni si debería dejar accesible el código al resto del mundo.

También he leído sobre la licencia `LVL` sin embargo lo que he podido entender es que restringes el acceso pero no sé si esto concierne también a derechos de modificación, distribución, comercialización, etc. que al inicio de la pregunta nombro.

Por último, mi aplicación utiliza `Google Maps` y me suena que al buscar información sobre cómo utilizarla vi en alguna parte de la documentación que había que agregar en algún sitio que estabas utilizando `Google Maps`. Sin embargo, he intentado buscarlo de nuevo y no he podido encontrar esa referencia.

Por lo tanto, tengo varias dudas:

- ¿Hay alguna licencia en específico que debería de usar para los requerimientos que pido (que tenga yo todos los derechos sobre la app)? ¿Tendría que usar `LVL`, `Apache`, ambas u otra que me cree yo?
- Si tengo que agregar la licencia de Apache en la aplicación ya que he usado código de la documentación de Android, ¿Dónde debería agregarlo? ¿Debería crear una pestaña dentro de la aplicación solamente para esa licencia?
- Usando `Google Maps` ¿Debo de agregar también que lo estoy utilizando? ¿También como otra pestaña de la aplicación?
- El logo y el hecho de que no me puedan copiar la aplicación (funcionalidad y nombre), ¿iría en la misma licencia que el resto de atribuciones? ¿Debería crear una patente para esto?
- ¿Es necesario que mi código esté abierto para que lo pueda ver todo el mundo?
- ¿Es necesario que registre también mi aplicación como patente?
- Al estar en España y usar `Google Play`, ¿estaré sujeto a las normativas de Estados Unidos o de la Unión Europea?

Llevo varias semanas leyendo documentación sobre licencias pero no consigo aclararme sobre cual utilizar ni si debería de usar simplemente una en concreto o todas en conjunto. No sé nada de leyes y la verdad que estoy bastante perdido actualmente.

**Nota:** Agradecería que las contestaciones fueran desde la experiencia pero agradeceré cualquier aclaración que pueda ayudarme a resolver las dudas con las licencias.

Comment: Supongo que tienes ya una cuenta d desarrollador?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Sí, la cuenta ya está creada, solo me falta asociarle a la aplicación las licencias necesarias para poder subirla.

Comment: No se puede patentar software, puedes tener derecho de autor.

Comment: @eyllanesc Osea si lo entiendo bien, ¿el software va con derechos autor como cualquier otro producto va con patentes?

Comment: @Error404 exacto

Comment: @eyllanesc Es decir, ¿si tu estableces que tienes los derechos de autor sobre un software tienes total dominio sobre ese software? ¿Para el logotipo y la aplicación en sí aplicaría la misma regla? Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones.

Comment: @Error404  ¿si tu estableces que tienes los derechos de autor sobre un software tienes total dominio sobre ese software?, no necesariamente ya que tu software depende de otros software, por lo que te tendrás que acoplar a sus licencias(en realidad uno debe de leer la licencia antes de utilizaro). El Logotipo es otra cosa. La aplicación es lo mismo que el código(software)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50974/discussion-between-error404-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: normalmente la licencia es de "uso" digamos que tu siempre eres el propietario y el usuario/cliente obten una licencia para usar el software, siguiendo el contrato, vaya lo de siempre que se debe usar con fines licitos, que declinas toda la responsibilidad de mal funcionamiento o mal uso etc.. depende de que licencia va vinculada que tu app debe ser de código visible etc...

Comment: @Webserveis Por eso la pregunta de, ¿debería de crear yo mi propia licencia? Y me refiero a licencias que certifiquen que esa app es mía.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Conceptos

Cuando distribuyes una aplicación informática debes definir cuales son los términos de uso, esto se puede hacer mediante un [**contrato de software**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licencia_de_software) que es válido según la legislación del país en el cual se distribuye la aplicación. Existen distintos tipos de contratos como de arriendo o de compra, pero siempre estos están sujetos a una licencia. Una forma bastante común de presentar el contrato al usuario es el [wrap-agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement).

Un tema diferente es el **copyright o derechos de autor**. Esto se refiere a la autoría de una obra. Los derechos de autor son solo una de las formas de propiedad intelectual y una obra tiene inmediatamente derechos de autor después de ser fijada su creación, aunque mediante un acuerdo expreso por el autor se puede renunciar, ceder, etc.

> La protección del derecho de autor existe desde que la obra es creada de una forma fijada. El derecho de autor sobre una obra creada se convierte inmediatamente en propiedad del autor que creó dicha obra. Solo el autor o aquellos cuyos derechos derivan del autor pueden reclamar propiedad, aunque cada pais suele tener oficinas donde se pueden registrar las obras. [Derecho de autor, Wikipedia.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derecho_de_autor)

Un acuerdo expreso (o licencia) permite un uso legitimo de la obra por parte de los demás, un ejemplo es el autor que decide cobrar por su obra (generalmente todos los derechos reservados), para quien la compra, su uso es legitimo; por otra parte algunos autores usan licencias como [creative commons](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons) que les permite renunciar a ciertos derechos (algunos derechos reservados).

> Las licencias Creative Commons no reemplazan a los derechos de autor, sino que se apoyan en estos para permitir modificar los términos y condiciones de la licencia de su obra de la manera que mejor satisfaga sus necesidades. [Creative commons, Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons)

En casos como el software es necesario que el autor emita una licencia (que a veces incluye un contrato), esto permite aclarar aspectos legales relacionados al uso, como *quien es el responsable en caso de error del software*. En pocas palabras las [licencias](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NG6NB42) son las declaraciones de los permisos de uso de las obras. GitHub provee una [guia](http://choosealicense.com/) para seleccionar la licencia correcta (en inglés).

Cuando un autor o empresa desea identificar su producto o servicio, la mayoría de paises proveen las [**marcas comerciales**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_(registro)). Estos registros protegen el nombre, el lema, el logotipo y otros elementos identificativos de una marca contra usos no autorizados por parte de terceros con fines determinados.

Ademas de las marcas registradas existen las **patentes de software**:

> Son títulos que reconocen el derecho de explotar en exclusiva durante 20 años funcionalidades, algoritmos, representaciones y otras acciones que se pueden llevar a cabo con una computadora y que conceden algunas oficinas de patentes en el mundo. [Patentes de software, Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patente_de_software)

Con respecto a las patentes de software, existe una controversia entre la legislación de EEUU y la de la Unión Europea, quienes son los principales representantes de cada parte. Muchas de las patentes que son válidas en EEUU no lo son en Europa, donde uno de los casos donde se puede ver esta diferencia es el de SAS Institute contra World Programming donde la Corte de Justicia de la Unión Europea concluye que:

> Article 1(2) of the Computer Programs Directive (Council Directive 91/250/EEC of 14 May 1991) must be interpreted as meaning that neither the functionality of a computer program nor the programming language and the format of data files used in a computer program in order to exploit certain of its functions constitute a form of expression of that program and, as such, are not protected by copyright in computer programs for the purposes of that directive. [SAS Institute Inc v World Programming Ltd, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_Institute_Inc_v_World_Programming_Ltd)

Articulos relacionados: [FayerWayer](https://www.fayerwayer.com/2012/05/union-europea-el-lenguaje-de-programacion-no-puede-ser-protegido-por-copyright/), [Reuters](http://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-eu-copyright-software-idUKBRE8410O720120502), [Directives](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:111:0016:0022:EN:PDF), [Directives History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Programs_Directive)

Esto quiere decir tu software puede ser copiado en funcionalidad en algunos lugares, ya que en el derecho de autor no se protege la idea sino la expresión y la funcionalidad no constituyen una forma de expresión de dicho programa debido a que la UE define expresión como código fuente.

Aun así, para tener un registro de propiedad intelectual o marca registrada, se debe acudir a la oficina del país respectivo. En el sitio de la OMPI existe una [lista de estos organismos por país](http://www.wipo.int/directory/es/urls.jsp).

### Google play

El contrato de google play con sus usuarios comienza a regir desde que el descarga o compra el contenido, este tiene [condiciones del servicio](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_es/about/play-terms.html) que define lo que el usuario puede y no hacer con el este. Esto quiere decir que en caso de que se viole alguna de las clausulas, el emisor del contrato/licencia puede terminarlo e incluso llevarle a juicio por no respetar las condiciones.

> No. Google no tiene autoridad para mediar en disputas sobre derechos de autor. Si recibimos un aviso de retirada válido y completo, retiraremos el contenido tal como exige la ley. Si recibimos una reclamación válida contra una notificación, la reenviaremos a la persona que solicitó la retirada. Si la disputa continúa a partir de ahí, serán las partes involucradas quienes deberán resolver el asunto en los tribunales. [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/legal/answer/3463239?hl=es-419&ref_topic=4558877)

Ademas Google Play permite impedir el acceso a tu aplicación a ciertos países ya que no todos los países tienen una legislación propicia para tu aplicación y no estas obligado a distribuirla en todos.

Por otra parte, también define un acuerdo de distribución en el que el desarrollador (quien publica la aplicación) debe cumplir ciertos requisitos y ceder ciertos derechos no exclusivos que permiten a Google Play mostrar recursos y distribuir la aplicación. Lo mas importante está en estos parafos:

> **5.4.** El Desarrollador concede al usuario una licencia no exclusiva, mundial y perpetua para ejecutar, mostrar y utilizar el Producto en el Dispositivo. El usuario puede incluir, entre otros, un grupo familiar con un administrador y miembros de la familia cuyas cuentas estén unidas con el propósito de crear dicho grupo. Los grupos familiares en Google Play están sujetos a límites razonables para evitar el uso inadecuado de las funciones para compartir con la familia. Los usuarios que pertenezcan a un grupo familiar pueden comprar una sola copia del Producto y compartirla con otros miembros de su grupo familiar (excepto en el caso de las suscripciones y los Productos en la aplicación, que no se pueden compartir). Si el Desarrollador habilita en Developer Console la opción para que los usuarios puedan compartir los Productos comprados anteriormente, esta autorización estará sujeta al presente Acuerdo. Si el Desarrollador lo desea, puede incluir un Acuerdo de Licencia de Usuario Final (EULA) independiente en su Producto para que rija los derechos de sus usuarios. No obstante, si se produce un conflicto con el EULA, este Acuerdo lo sustituirá.
>
> **5.5.** El Desarrollador manifiesta y garantiza que dispone de todos los derechos de propiedad intelectual, incluyendo las patentes, las marcas comerciales, los secretos comerciales, los derechos de autor u otros derechos de propiedad necesarios relacionados con el Producto. Si utiliza materiales de terceros, el Desarrollador manifiesta y garantiza que dispone del derecho para distribuir dicho material en el Producto. El Desarrollador acepta que no enviará material a la Tienda que tenga derechos de copyright, esté protegido por secretos comerciales o esté sujeto de cualquier otra forma a derechos de propiedad de terceros, incluidos patentes, derechos de publicidad y de privacidad, a menos que sea el propietario de dichos derechos o tenga permiso del propietario legítimo para enviar el material. [Acuerdo de Distribución para Desarrolladores de Google Play](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_es/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html)

***(La cita anterior podría cambiar con el tiempo, recordar que corresponde con la fecha de esta respuesta)***

### Aclaraciones

- [**LVL**](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) no es un tipo de licencia. LVL es un marco de trabajo y servicio de Google Play que permite facilitar la verificación de licencias de las aplicaciones que distribuyes a traves de la tienda.
- [**DMCA**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) es una ley de Estados Unidos que sanciona la violación de los derechos de autor (y otras infracciones). Para hacer una reclamacion en EEUU debes ponerte en contacto con la [The United States Copyright Office](https://www.copyright.gov/). Hay que recordar que esto es solo valido para infracciones dentro del territorio de EEUU y podría no tener efecto en otros países. El sitio [www.dmca.com (Digital Millennium Copyright Act Services Ltd.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) una empresa no asociada al gobierno Estadounidense que ofrece enviar solicitudes a la corte sobre infracciones de copyright.
- > ¿Hay alguna licencia en específico que debería de usar para los requerimientos que pido?

  Si quieres distribuir una aplicación comercial o privada solo no entregues el código fuente, mantenlo siempre seguro y privado. Debes redactar un contrato o licencia personalizada que declare las políticas y términos de uso de uso (prohibición de copia, redistribución, decompilación, etc), de privacidad, de propiedad intelectual del desarrollador como del contenido del usuario (solo si tu aplicación permite crear o subir contenido), etc. Algunos ejemplos de licencias de los servicios/productos que frecuento son: [Whatsapp](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/#terms-of-service), [DeviantArt](http://about.deviantart.com/policy/service/), [Pinterest](https://about.pinterest.com/es/terms-service), [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_spanish.htm), [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/)
- > ¿Debería crear una pestaña dentro de la aplicación solamente para esa licencia? ¿Debo de agregar también que lo estoy utilizando? ¿Es necesario que registre también mi aplicación como patente?

  Si. Debes agregar una pestaña o sección de ayuda, donde debes mostrar la licencia, las licencias de software de terceros (third-party) y todo lo del punto anterior. Ademas de los datos de contacto y ese tipo de información. Recuerda que hay licencias que obligan a declarar su uso y los autores como [Apache](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License) y otras que no te permiten apropiarte del software como [GNU](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) por lo que debes usar la misma licencia y liberar el código fuente. Para obtener una patente o marca comercial debes acercarte la oficina de tu pais (el link está arriba). Puedes entrar a la aplicación de Facebook o Whatsapp y navegar hasta la parte de licencias/ayuda para hacerte una idea de como presentar el contenido.
- > Usando Google Maps ¿Debo de agregar también que lo estoy utilizando?

  Te recomiendo que leas los términos de uso de [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). Si tu aplicación es de paga, el servicio deja de ser gratuito.
- > Al estar en España y usar Google Play, ¿estaré sujeto a las normativas de Estados Unidos o de la Unión Europea?

  Las normativas a las que estas restringido son:

  - Directiva 91/250/CEE de 14 de mayo, sobre la protección jurídica de los programas de ordenador (traspuesta en España con la Ley 16/1993)
  - Ley de Propiedad Intelectual 1/1996
  - Existen normativas internacionales que permiten proteger los programas de ordenador a nivel mundial (Convenio de Berna para la Protección de las Obras Literarias y Artísticas y el Tratado de la OMPI sobre los derechos de autor).

  Puedes buscar en internet *protección legal software*, puedes encontrar artículos como [Protección legal del software en España](http://www.roithers.com/es/proteccion-legal-software/)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Gracias por una información tan completa. Me va a costar varios días asimilar toda la información y llevarla a cabo pero es un gran comienzo.

Comment: un granito de arena: en esta respuesta se explica detalladamente las diferencias entre GPL y otras licencias permisivas, como Apache: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/438/25 y cuando es necesario o no publicar el código fuente. Por ejemplo, si tu app tiene una lado servidor, de ese lado podrias usar GPL pero del lado compilado no. Salu2

Answer (score 2):

[Arie](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42076/127) publicó una respuesta excelente que cubre todos los puntos de la pregunta. Me parece oportuno ampliar solamente en cuanto a la licencia de Google Maps.

Lo que viene a continuación es una simplificación de los términos y condiciones de servicio y, como tal, es una interpretación personal de lo que me parece pertinente (y que podría quedar desactualizado). Para referirse a los términos y condiciones, se debe leer el documento *[Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)*.

### Google Maps

#### Licencia de Servicio

- Google otorga una licencia no exclusiva, mundial, personal, intransferible, no cedible, no sublicenciable y libre de regalías para utilizar el Servicio.

#### Licencia de Contenido

- Google otorga una licencia no exclusiva, mundial, personal, intransferible, no asignable, no sublicenciable y libre de regalías para utilizar el Contenido en la implementación de la API de Google Maps.

#### Restricciones

- No se permite mostrar las marcas de Google en ninguna forma que pareciera implicar que tu producto tiene una relación o afiliación, patrocinio o respaldo con Google que vaya más allá de lo que se entiende por uso del servicio.
- De la misma forma, tu contenido no puede ser presentado de una forma que parezca creado por Google.
- No se puede utilizar el servicio si cualquiera de tus productos muestra contenido para adultos (incluídos tabaco y alcohol) o promueve actividades ilegales de cualquier tipo.
- Modificar, utilizar o alterar las marcas o los logos de Google en otra forma que no sea la que se muestra en el mapa (ni más grandes, ni más chicos, ni distorsionados).

#### Requisitos

(no desesperes hasta leer las excepciones)

- Debe ser accesible al público en general **sin cargo alguno** y no debe requerir una suscripción que implique cargos u otro acceso restringido. En caso de querer comercializarlo, se debe contratar un servicio diferente (i.e. *Enterprise*).
- No debe funcionar exclusivamente detrás de un firewall; sólo en una LAN (excepto durante desarrollo y prueba); ni en una comunidad cerrada.

**Excepciones a estos requisitos:**

- Acuerdo Enterprise con Google, con el permiso escrito por Google.
- **Aplicaciones móviles**. El requisito de ser accesible sin cargo **no se aplica** si se utiliza en una aplicación móvil que se comercializa a través de una tienda en línea y se puede descargar a un dispositivo móvil, siempre y cuando **no sea una aplicación en Android que utilice además otro servicio de mapas**.

**Ejemplos:**

- La aplicación puede solicitar que inicien sesión siempre y cuando no haya tarifas extras asociadas a este acceso.
- **La aplicación puede ser paga** si es distribuida a través de Google Play Store.
- Puedes cobrarle a tus clientes una tarifa por servicios de consultoría o hosting, pero no por la implementación de la API de Google Maps.

#### Condiciones de servicio

Deberás:

- Mostrar a los usuarios el vínculo a los Términos de servicio de Google, tal cual son presentados por el servicio (en el mapa), de la forma descrita en la [Documentación de la API de Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/);
- Explicitar dentro de los términos de uso de tu aplicación que, al usar tu implementación de la API de Maps, los usuarios están de acuerdo en cumplir con los Términos de servicio de Google.
- Proteger los derechos legales y de privacidad de dichos usuarios.
- **Hacer pública la política de privacidad de tu aplicación**, en concordancia con la de la API de Google Maps y respetarla. Dentro de tu política de privacidad, deberás notificarle a los usuarios que estás utilizando la API de Google Maps, incorporando la referencia a http://www.google.com/policies/privacy.
- En particular, si se te permite, o se le permite a cualquier otra parte acceder a la información de los usuarios (personal o de ubicación) la política de privacidad debe describir su uso y almacenamiento de esta información.
- Notificar previamente al usuario los tipos de datos que se podrán recopilar (del usuario o del dispositivo). No se deberá obtener o almacenar en caché la ubicación de ningún usuario de ninguna manera, excepto con el consentimiento previo del usuario. Se deberá permitir que el usuario pueda revoca este consentimiento  en cualquier momento.
- Si se utilizan cookies, para los usuarios de la Unión Europea, deberás cumplir con la [Política de consentimiento del usuario de la UE](http://www.google.com/about/company/user-consent-policy.html).

#### Restricciones

- **No podrás utilizar el servicio para el Seguimiento de Activos**, a menos que se contrate una licencia Enterprise (o un *Plan Premium*, o *Maps API for Work* que lo indiquen explícitamente).
- A menos que la documentación lo permita expresamente, **no podrás utilizar el contenido si no es sobre un mapa de Google**. Por ejemplo, se permite mostrar imágenes de Street View sin el mapa, porque la documentación lo dice explícitamente.

---

#### Tu licencia a Google

- Google no reclama ninguna propiedad sobre tu contenido y conserva los derechos de autor y otros derechos que ya posees en tu contenido.
- Le otorgas a Google una licencia no exclusiva, mundial, sublicenciable y libre de regalías para utilizar tus Bondades de Marca y tu Contenido para publicitar o anunciar que estás utilizando el Servicio de Google (incluyendo enlaces a tu sitio web).